# Delete old data from program

Tags: c++

I have to code, build, and execute a program that requires sequential files to create an address database.  The program works but When I re-run the program the old data is still in the database when I chose to display records.  How do I get the program to erase old data and start fresh when I start the program from the beginning.  Can you please help identify my errors.  Thank you in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
void menu(void);
void writeData(void);
void readData(void);
string * split(string, char);

const char FileName[] = "TestAddress.txt"; //File name from where to read the characters


int main()
{
    menu();
    return 0;

}

void menu(void)
{
    //Display main menu and call relevant functions
    char input;
    while (1)
    {
        //allow user to choose to append records, display records or exit the program
        cout << "Select program\n(A)ppend Records, (D)isplay Records, (E)xit: ";
        cin >> input;
        cout << endl;

        if (input == 'A' || input == 'a')
            writeData();//Append data to the file
        else if (input == 'D' || input == 'd')
            readData(); //Read records from the file and display
        else if (input == 'E' || input == 'e')
            exit(0);// Exit application 
        else
            cout << endl << "Invalid Input!!! Please enter A, D or E:" << endl; //In case of invalid input, menu will be displayed again
    }
}//end menu
void writeData(void) {//Append data to the file
    string fullName, Street, City, State, ZipCode, input;
    fstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open(FileName, fstream::app); //Open the file with append mode

    do {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Please enter Name: ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, fullName);     //Input Name

        cout << "Please enter Street: ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, Street); //Input Street Address

        cout << "Please enter City: ";
        cin >> City; //Input City

        cout << "Please enter State: ";
        cin >> State;// Input State

        cout << "Please enter ZipCode: ";
        cin >> ZipCode; //Input Zipcode
        cout << endl;

        outputFile << fullName << "," << Street << "," << City << "," << State << "," << ZipCode << endl; //Write all data to the file

        do 
        {
            cout << "Enter Another Record?(Y/N): ";
            cin >> input;//In case if user wants to enter another rcord
        } 
        while (input != "Y"&& input != "y" && input != "N"&& input != "n"); //Until the user presses 'y' or 'n'

    } while (input == "Y" || input == "y"); //If user wants to add another record continue or else display menu again

    outputFile.close(); //Close file


}//end write data
void readData(void) {//Read records from the file and display
    string  Name, Street, City, State, ZipCode;
    char* line = new char[2000]; //pointing to a vriable that will be having a record detail
    ifstream inputFile;
    int RecordNumber = 1;
    inputFile.open(FileName, fstream::in);//Open the file with read mode

    while (!inputFile.eof())
    {
        inputFile.getline(line, 2000); //Read one record from the file      

        string * fields = split(line, ',');//Split the records based on the prsence of ','

        if (fields[0] == "") //In case of '\n' has encountered
            continue; //Stop processing and continue the loop again
        cout << "" << endl;

        cout << "Record #" << RecordNumber << endl; //Displaying record with style
        cout << "Name.........." << fields[0] << endl;
        cout << "Street........" << fields[1] << endl;
        cout << "City.........." << fields[2] << endl;
        cout << "State........." << fields[3] << endl;
        cout << "Zip Code......" << fields[4] << endl;
        cout << endl << "-------------------------------------------------------" << endl << endl;
        RecordNumber++; //Increment record number
    }

}//end read data
string * split(string theLine, char theDeliminator) {
    //determine how many splits there will be so we can size our array
    int splitCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < theLine.size(); i++)
    {
        //Read the whole string (theLine) and count for all ',' encountered
        if (theLine[i] == theDeliminator)
            splitCount++;
    }
    splitCount++; //add one more to the count because there is not an ending comma 
                  //create an array to hold the fields
    string* theFieldArray;
    theFieldArray = new string[splitCount];
    //split the string into seperate fields
    string theField = "";
    int commaCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < theLine.size(); i++)
    {
        //read each character and look for the deliminator
        if (theLine[i] != theDeliminator) {
            theField += theLine[i]; //build the field
        }
        else { //the deliminator was hit so save to the field to the array
            theFieldArray[commaCount] = theField; //save the field to the array
            theField = "";
            commaCount++;
        }
    }
    theFieldArray[commaCount] = theField; //the last field is not marked with a comma...

    return theFieldArray;
} //end split
```

Comment: You may want to read this: [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, you may want to read this: [How to debug small programs?](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: One question per question please. It keeps things understandable for the next person with your issue.